# Module is extraneous npm

Tags: npm, node-modules, solidity, truffle

I've checked that the `connect-privkey-to-provider` module is in the dependencies. However, it keeps saying ***Module 'connect-privkey-to-provider' is extraneous npm*** and ***cannot find module 'connect-privkey-to-provider'***.

What's wrong with my code?

> PS C:\Users\1Sun\addition-game-starter> truffle deploy --network
> klaytn
> **Error: Cannot find module 'connect-privkey-to-provider'**
> at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:582:15)
> at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:508:25)
> at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
> at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:18)
> at Object. (C:\Users\1Sun\addition-game-starter\truffle.js:2:29)
> at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:701:30)
> at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:712:10)
> at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:600:32)
> at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:539:12)
> at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:531:3)
> at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
> at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:18)
> at Function.Config.load (C:\Users\1Sun\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\packages\truffle-config\index.js:254:1)
> at Function.Config.detect (C:\Users\1Sun\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\packages\truffle-config\index.js:243:1)
> at Object.run (C:\Users\1Sun\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\packages\truffle-core\lib\commands\migrate.js:35:1)
> at Command.run (C:\Users\1Sun\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\packages\truffle-core\lib\command.js:101:1)
> at Object. (C:\Users\1Sun\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\packages\truffle-core\cli.js:22:1)
> at **webpack_require** (C:\Users\1Sun\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\webpack\bootstrap
> 0791995565e53f633c90:19:1)
> at C:\Users\1Sun\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\webpack\bootstrap
> 0791995565e53f633c90:65:1
> at Object. (C:\Users\1Sun\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\cli.bundled.js:71:10)
> at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:701:30)

---

**package.json**

```json
{
  "name": "klay-dapp-boilerplate",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "boilerplate for klaytn-based app",
  "main": "truffle.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack",
    "dev": "webpack-dev-server"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "caver-js": "^0.0.2-m",
    "connect-privkey-to-provider": "^0.0.3",
    "spin.js": "^4.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^4.6.0",
    "eslint": "^4.19.1",
    "webpack": "^4.7.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.1.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.4"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "env": {
      "browser": true,
      "node": true
    }
  }
}
```

---

**truffle.js**

```js
// truffle.js config for klaytn.
const PrivateKeyConnector = require('connect-privkey-to-provider')
const NETWORK_ID = '1001'
const GASLIMIT = '20000000'
const URL ='https://api.baobab.klaytn.net:8651'
const PRIVATE_KEY = '0x80ea7e298ba2cbf484e6c0c0703ccf2ea94be7f8a1a097fc013042b4888a2e80'

module.exports = {
    networks: {
        klaytn: {
            provider: new PrivateKeyConnector(PRIVATE_KEY, URL),
            network_id: NETWORK_ID,
            gas: GASLIMIT,
            gasPrice: null,
        }
    }
}
```

**Error**

[image]

[image]

Comment: share please your code to install and launch

Comment: @YegorZaremba I'm sorry for late response, you can see it by `git clone https://github.com/kkagill/addition-game-starter.git` and paste **truffle.js** code which I've added on my question and then excute `truffle deploy --network klaytn` in terminal!

Comment: scripts section would also be important; maybe there are too many `-- --`

Answer (score 14):

Your code works fine in my environment. Try to do these:

- Remove `node_modules`
- Remove `package-lock.json`
- Update `truffle` package `npm update -g truffle`
- Reinstall, using command `npm i`

After that just change `solidity version` in `contracts` folder

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;
```

Comment: When I tried to do the first step `remove node_modules`, it kept causing errors.. I uploaded the image showing the error part

Comment: use this command: `rmdir node_modules` and `del package-lock.json`

Answer (score 2):

In my case for changing some dependencies, I was deleting **node_modules**, but I had to erase  **package-lock.json** too.

I closed all windows, deleted **node_modules** folder and **package-lock.json** and reinstalled it all again with **npm install**.