# Cannot find module 'fs-extra' when testing with Truffle

Tags: npm, node-modules, solidity, truffle

I am reading the tutorial on [Ethereum Pet Shop -- Your First DApp](https://www.trufflesuite.com/tutorials/pet-shop#directory-structure), everything seems ok until I test with `truffle test` with below error:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'fs-extra'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:636:15)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:562:25)
at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:690:17)
at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
at Object.call (/Users/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/truffle/node_modules/@truffle/debugger/dist/external "fs-extra":1:18)
at r (/Users/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/truffle/node_modules/@truffle/debugger/dist/webpack/bootstrap:19:22)
[...]
Truffle v5.2.4 (core: 5.2.4)
Node v10.16.0
```

I have tried some suggestions as in [Module is extraneous npm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56221938/module-is-extraneous-npm), but the `Error: Cannot find module 'fs-extra'` insists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add it to your `package.json` and install the package.

1. Either run

   ```
   npm install --save fs-extra
   ```

   The `--save` option will add it to the `package.json` for you.
2. Or add it manually to the `package.json` section `dependencies`

   ```
   "dependencies": {
       "fs-extra": "^9.1.0"
   }
   ```

   and then install it

   ```
   npm install
   ```

   Version 9.1.0 is the current version according to [npmjs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fs-extra)

Comment: Thanks for your swift support! It worked: 
`TestAdoption
    ✓ testUserCanAdoptPet (138ms)
    ✓ testGetAdopterAddressByPetId (146ms)
    ✓ testGetAdopterAddressByPetIdInArray (182ms)
  3 passing (12s)`

Answer (score 0):

*fs-extra*-package should be delivered as part of *truffle* and I would not recommend installing it to the project.

To fix it on Ubuntu follow these steps:

```sh
# stop apps/tools that using truffle - ganache-cli, etc.

# uninstall truffle
sudo npm uninstall -g truffle

# install truffle again
sudo npm install -g truffle

# check that fs-extra packaged installed
ls -lh  /usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/node_modules | grep fs-extra
```

Comment: You should not use sudo with npm install